# Return category from second table if exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with standard categories and one with edited categories. If an edited category exist in table 2, the title should be fetched from there. Do I use JOIN or how do I do it?

```
Table 1: id, title
Table 2: id, parent_id, title
```

Content:

```
Table 1
id: 1 title: cat1
id: 2 title: cat2

Table 2
id: 1 parent_id: 1 title: Category 1
```

Return:

```
id: 1 title: Category 1
id: 2 title: cat2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    CASE
WHEN b.title IS NULL THEN
    a.title
ELSE
    b.title
END as title
FROM
    t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b ON a.id = b.parent_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! I found this. Would it do the exact same thing or is it different? `coalesce(b.title, a.title) as title`